# Throwing error in python views.py while running

Tags: list, indexing, range, out

def view_issued_book(request):
issuedBooks = IssuedBook.objects.all()
details = []
for i in issuedBooks:
days = (date.today()-i.issued_date)
d=days.days
fine=0
if d>14:
day=d-14
fine=day*5
books = list(models.Book.objects.filter(isbn=i.isbn))
students = list(models.Student.objects.filter(user=i.student_id))
i=0
for l in books:
t=(students[i].user,students[i].user_id,books[i].name,books[i].isbn,issuedBooks[0].issued_date,issuedBooks[0].expiry_date, fine)
i=i+1
details.append(t)
return render(request, "view_issued_book.html", {'issuedBooks':issuedBooks, 'details':details})
#This is views.py coding.The 't=' line is showing error.

```
path("view_issued_book/", views.view_issued_book, name="view_issued_book"),
```

#This is uls.py code